# valueOf function set to always return the same value

Tags: javascript

This:

```
% node
> var o = {valueOf: function() { return 5; } };
undefined
> o += 1;
6
> o
6
> o += 1;
7
> o
7
```

Why is `o` value incremented if `valueOf` always returns 5?

Comment: Because when you do `o += 1` it's not an object any more. It's `6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from the situation where `o` references the object as seen in the question:

```
var o = {valueOf: function() { return 5; } };
```

Then in the expression

```
o += 1;
```

what happens is:

1. The value of `o` is obtained as a number, via the call to `.valueOf()`
2. That value is added to `1`, giving `6`
3. That result is assigned to the variable `o`

Thus the variable `o`, which once contained a reference to an object, now contains a number.

Comment: Which is also seen when `o` is issued and the printed result is `6`.

Comment: I understand that, but coming from other programming languages it does not seem like completely sane behavior. Try `o = object(); o+=1` in Python.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U well, looks alright to me in JS. After all, `a = 1` followed by `a = "hello"` works in the same way - it overwrites what is stored in `a`. When you do `a = a + b` then the result will again overwrite what is in `a`. It's consistent. The fact that it does type coercion is irrelevant, although, yes - type coercion can change the variable type: `a = 42; a += "hello"` will result in a string.

Comment: @vlaz Except that `+=` should be seen as "increment by" operator rather then "x = x + increment" which involves reassignment of x. E.g. Python treats `+=` this way.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U From the languages I've used - C, C++, Ruby, C#, PHP and Java don't: `+=` is always a shorthand for `x = x +`. JavaScript follows the same thing. Really, Python will be the _only_ language I know of that treats `+=` differently. The major difference is that other languages are statically typed and won't allow incompatible types. However, even, say, Java will do auto-boxing/unboxing for `Integer a = 1; a += 2;` or the like and _will_ overwrite `a`. Conversely `int b = 1; b += new Integer(7)` will only "increment" because the object will be dismantled. It's still an overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are assigning `o = 5`, then you are incrementing the value, by doing `+= 1` and then you're querying the new value, which has now changed, increased by one, hence `o = 6`. You're switching from object to a value when you're doing the first incrementation on the object!

Answer (score 0):

The `valueOf()` method returns the primitive value of the specified object. What happened above is,

1. `o` is first assigned as object as below,

   var o = {valueOf: function() { return 5; } };
2. When you use `o += 1;`, you are here using `o` as `primitive` type and JavaScript calls the `valueOf` method to convert an `object` in to a `primitive` type
3. Hence, `o` is no longer `object` but converted as `primitive` type with value of `6 = 5 + 1` and started incremented with `o += 1;`

Hope it clarifies.